# SSMS float and decimal presentation

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, decimal, ssms, regional-settings

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding output format in SSMS.

**Tablea**:

- fielda = float
- fieldb = decimal(18,6)

**SQL**:

```
select
  sum(cast(fielda as decimal(18,6))) a,
  sum(fieldb) b
from tablea
```

**Result in Grid, text**:

```
a               b
-4208.370000    -4208,37
-2945.830000    -2945,83
31547.610000    31547,61
```

So float = ',', decimal = '.'

Is this a regional setting(local), SSMS setting(app) or database?

The last does not seem to be the case, the result differs per location(pc). I asume that both float and decimal can be considered a 'number', so regional setting seems odd. And any any SSMS setting is not know to me.

Is there a way to fix this? And how to fix this(=same result)?

SSMS 10
PC Regional settings NL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Your regional setting in the Control panel. I think its the problem with that.

Comment: I don't see a setting to change the wat a float or decimal works. Or do you mean that I should not use NL settings in my regional settings?

Comment: SSMS seems to ignore regional settings, at least when formatting results.

Comment: Just had this issue myself recently. The issue here is not whether SSMS ignores regional settings or not. It is that it ignores regional settings for decimal but not for float or money (it should either ignore it for all or none)